# Multiple Spinners in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have two spinners in my Android Activity and I' trying to write the Java code that handles them with one method.  I tried this, which is what I did with handling multiple buttons, but this doesn't work.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected(" + position + ") **********");
    Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected() View is (" + v + ") **********");
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.SpinnerTaxRate :
            ....
            break
        case R.id.SpinnerDiscount :
             ....
             break
```

The problem is that v.getId() isn't being set for the spinner.  How can I correct this?

Here is the XML for one of the spinners (the other is very similar):

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/SpinnerTaxRate"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

This is the code that registers the Spinner for the ItemSelectedListener.

```
    SpinnerTaxRate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerTaxRate);
    SpinnerTaxRate.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: set the id what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that none of those case statements ever gets executed.  I put Log.d() statements in there, and they don't show in the logs.  So that's why I think that the v.GetID() isn't working for the spinners.

Comment: have you set the id in the xml??

Comment: Can we see the XML for the spinners? If there's not an android:id, then add one.

Comment: and are these line printed??   ******** onItemSelected(...

Comment: Post the code, where you register the `Spinners` for the `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: I added the XML for the Spinners.

Comment: Yes, these are printed: ******** onItemSelected(...  And they print the correct position for that spinner.

Comment: Check my answer. You are checking for the wrong `View` id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are checking against `v` which is the `TextView` used inside the `Spinner`. You want to use the `AdapterView<?>`, or `parent` which is the actual `Spinner

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected(" + position + ") **********");
Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected() View is (" + v + ") **********");
switch(parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.SpinnerTaxRate :
        ....
        break
    case R.id.SpinnerDiscount :
         ....
         break
```

Comment: You are welcome. Just remember there is a `View` inside the `Spinner` to hold the `text` or value

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(parent.getId()) {
    case R.id.SpinnerTaxRate:
        ....
        break
```

use this instead. You have used wrong id

the parent.getId() returns the corresponding Id of view that you set in the layout. Here you have used SpinnerTaxRate as id but you r comaparing with spinner1. So compare the correct id.

**EDIT**
I overlooked the key part .. instead of v.getId()  use parent.getID(). parent. Here

```
parent  The AdapterView where the selection happened
v       The view within the AdapterView that was clicked
```

Comment: I'm sorry. In the actual code the IDs do match. I simplified it for this question only.  (so the problem persists)

Comment: Yes, the lines above the switch are printed, and they print the correct position for that spinner.

Comment: update your question with correct code that you actually used

Comment: Yes, I edited the original Java code in the question so now they do match.

Comment: oops sorry .. I also wrote wrong variable .. it should be parent.getID()

Answer (score 0):

The id of the spinner does not correspond to the switch statement

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/Spinner1" <-----
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

This would cause your switch statement to execute.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected(" + position + ") **********");
    Log.d(TAG, "******** onItemSelected() View is (" + v + ") **********");
    switch(parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.Spinner1 : <---
            ....
            break
        case R.id.Spinner2 :
             ....
             break
```

Comment: I'm sorry.  In the actual code the IDs do match.  I simplified it for this question only.

Comment: What? The id's match? They doesn't accordingly to your xml and java code. simplified? How do you call this simplified, when you are confusing yourself and the people trying to help you out?

Comment: I simplified the original code that I posted by changing the Spinner ID to Spinner1.  At that time, I wasn't intending to show the XML code, so it didn't matter.  But then. people asked for the XML code, and I forgot to also change that ID as well.  It's my mistake, and I'm sorry.  But the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help and I hope I didn't frustrate you.